# Only default Routing working in cakephp 3.6, may be issue with htaccess

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am download the cakephp 3.6 and when i am tring to use default route it works fine.  but when i  add something after / . it git me 404 error here is my router code

```
 $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);


$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
```

when I request for http://localhost/cake/my_app_name/ it work fine
but when I hit for http://localhost/cake/my_app_name/pages/10 it gives me 404 error

my webroot htaccess file code  is here

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

app htaccess code is here

```
 # Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well, there is no route that matches `/page10`, so, that would be the expected behavior. You may want to double check that you're posting the correct code/URLs, and describe what exactly you want to do.

Comment: you are right. i just update the question . please check it again

Comment: Your route is for `/pages/`, your URL shows `/page/`.

Comment: already tried its also not working.
question updated for pages route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `AllowOverride All` directive to your app's folder in Apache config.

```
<Directory /var/www/your/app/dir> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All 
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file called 10.ctp and put it into src/Template/Pages.

Comment: Yhan how i can create dyaminc url

Comment: @anilsidhu Again, you should properly describe what _exactly_ you are trying to acomplish, "_dynamic URL_" is a very ambigous term.

Comment: just change the question title . now u can understand easily

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. You open

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. You open /pages/10  and the web server shows you a standard 404 error (not a CakePHP one). So, I think you have to add `AllowOverride All` directive to your app's folder in Apache config. `<Directory /var/www/your/app/dir>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: yes. this is resolve my issue. Please give this comment as a answer i will you give thumps up on the ans. :) . thank you so much